# Multiple rows with same identifier, how to select the row with heighest value (ignoring the rest) with multiple left joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

this issue has been bothering me for a few hours now. After finding out my old query had an issue, I had to rebuild it.

**The situation:**

I need to match each patient_id with a clinic_id, and for that I get all the appointments using the patient_id, 
find the highest appointment_id and use its clinic_id to set the last known clinic_id.

My old query did this, but it skipped patients that never had an appointment.

These are my current results, but I need to filter my results. Question is, how?

```
+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|   patient_id  |   country_code    |   appointment_id  |   clinic_id   |
+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|       111     |       UK          |       620         |       3       |
|       111     |       UK          |       621         |       2       |
|       111     |       UK          |       1995        |       1       |
|       222     |       UK          |       609         |       3       |
|       222     |       UK          |       610         |       2       |   
|       333     |       UK          |       null        |       null    |
|       444     |       UK          |       null        |       null    |
+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

What I want is the following:

```
+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|   patient_id  |   country_code    |   appointment_id  |   clinic_id   |
+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|       111     |       UK          |       1995        |       1       |
|       222     |       UK          |       610         |       2       |     
|       333     |       UK          |       null        |       null    |
|       444     |       UK          |       null        |       null    |
+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

I am using the following query right now:

```
SELECT 
    patient.id,
    systemcountry.country_code,
    appointment_patient.appointment_id,
    appointment.clinic_id
FROM
    patient
        LEFT JOIN
    systemcountry ON patient.country_id = systemcountry.id
        LEFT JOIN
    appointment_patient ON patient_id = patient.id
        LEFT JOIN
    appointment ON appointment_patient.appointment_id = appointment.id
```

This was my old query, which had an issue causing it to skip patients that never had an appointment:

```
SELECT
    patient.id AS patient_id,
    systemcountry.code AS systemcountry_code,
    appointment.clinic_id
FROM
    patient
        LEFT JOIN
    systemcountry ON patient.land_id = systemcountry.id,
    appointment
WHERE
    appointment.id = (SELECT
            MAX(appointment_id)
        FROM
            appointment_patient
        WHERE
            patient_id = patient.id);
```

I am still a beginner, so go easy on me.

I appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please show your DDL & EXPLAIN output--and the rest of a [mcve]. Please also investigate the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.

Comment: I took the shortcut and used two separate queries to get the results I wanted. The queries were used in a database conversion application. Thanks for all the input guys!

Comment: Hi. Please consider posting an answer to your question & (later) accepting it. PS If things take a long time on such a simple query, read about indexes.  If you had posted and MCVE then answerers could have addressed that if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Move the sub-select in your original query's WHERE clause into a LEFT JOIN  (something like this):

```
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(appointment_id), patient_id
        FROM appointment_patient
        GROUP BY patient_id)  as apt ON patient.patient_id=apt.patient_id
```

Comment: For clarification, in rather large databases I would recommend understanding how this performs and how to optimize queries like these.

Comment: I will try your solution when I get back in the office Monday.

Answer (score 0):

You can try function *`max()`* over columns whose only highest value you want, then group by the result set using `patient.id`

```
SELECT 
    patient.id,
    systemcountry.country_code,
    max(appointment_patient.appointment_id),
    appointment.clinic_id
FROM
    patient
        LEFT JOIN
            systemcountry ON patient.country_id = systemcountry.id
        LEFT JOIN
            appointment_patient ON patient_id = patient.id
        LEFT JOIN
            appointment ON appointment_patient.appointment_id = appointment.id
GROUP BY patient.id
```

Comment: I tried this before I went home, but stopped the query because it was running more than 10 minutes to get results. There is about a million appointments in our database with about 30k patients.

Comment: I tried it again today and it ran for a few minutes, before my connection timed out.